# Retrieve the current second in the Youtube video on my site using Youtube API in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api

I want to retrieve the current second in the Youtube video on my site using Youtube API in Zend.

I didn't find any information on this in google.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "current second?"

Comment: I guess he means you play the video and then want to fetch the second where the playback is at. Guess there might be some js way to do it.

Comment: I meant from the beginning of the video playback (using JS). But I've alreay found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will answer my own question for future viewers to see the solution to the problem.
You can do that using the youtube JavaScript API: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

```
player.getCurrentTime():Number
Returns the elapsed time in seconds since the video started playing.
```